# Ionic - Change css of shadow class in html

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a side menu always visible in my ionic aplication, the problem is I don't know how to change the #shadow-root css, I tried a few things but still don't work.
[image]
The problem is that when I make the menu smaller and empty space is left there. I want to remove that empty space, because when the screen is bigger the empty space is even bigger.
[image]
I searched in the debug console and this is the troublesome element:
[image]

This is my code:

HTML:

```
  <ion-split-pane contentId="side-menu" class="menu-left" when="md">

    <ion-menu side="start" menuId="side-menu" contentId="side-menu" mode="md" class="menu2">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
    
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list lines="none" class="menu-content">

          <ion-item (click)="navigateHome()">
            <ion-icon name="home" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Inicio</ion-label>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item (click)="navigateAnimes()">
            <ion-icon name="library" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Animes</ion-label>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item (click)="navigateMine()">
            <ion-icon name="bookmarks" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Mi lista</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
    
          <ion-item (click)="navigateSettings()">
            <ion-icon name="options" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Ajustes</ion-label>
          </ion-item>

        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <ion-router-outlet id="side-menu"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-left{
    --width: 200px;
}

.menu-content {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to apply my css attributes to the inner-scroll scroll-y in the shadow class please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me for now:

```
.split-pane-visible > ion-menu {
    max-width: 200px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@phantomiam123 I updated my css class and doesn't work:
My css class now is:

```
.menu-left{
    --width: 200px;
}

.menu-content {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 200px;
}

.inner-scroll .scroll-y {  
    width: 200px;
}
```

And in the debug console:
[image]